# How to fix the additive shifts in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib, in its infinite wisdom, wants to set the limits of the plots to divulge as much information as possible. Thus, if I understood correctly, it locates the maximum and minimum points on the plot, determines ticks around this vicinity and prepares additive and/or multiplicative descriptions for these points.

[image]

However, when someone tries to verify a formula, i.e., would be very happy if the lines overlap, such plots might be misleading. In the above example, the difference is around the order of 1e-10.

What I would prefer is to have an additive fix easy to understand. For the example above, +5e7 would make well. Then, the yticks has to be all negative. The below figure shows the same relation after I manually subtract 5e7 from both functions. Much easier to understand.

[image]

So, is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/howto_faq.html#prevent-ticklabels-from-having-an-offset

Comment: In the above example, the difference is around 6e-4, not in the order of 1e-10

Comment: @Stef 1 is around 5e7 and 2 is around 5e7-6e-4. So, I took the relative difference to demonstrate how close they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the offset by first drawing the plot (without actually rendering it) and then use [`get_offset`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=get_offset#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.get_offset) to get the offset (note: the offset can be both a multiplicative factor and an addivitive offset, where the latter is always preceded by `+` or `-`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1]
y1 = np.array([5e7, 5e7])
y2 = y1 - 6e-4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y1)
ax.plot(x, y2)
fig.draw_without_rendering()
offset = float(offset) if (offset := ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().get_offset().lstrip('0123456789eE')) else 0
ax.clear()

ax.plot(x, y1 - offset)
ax.plot(x, y2 - offset)
ax.set_ylabel(f'Value - {offset:g}')
```

[image]